# How to pass the object property as param to Struts custom validator

Tags: java, struts2, ognl, xml-validation, xwork

This is the custom validator, has getters/setters for `countryCode`

```java
public void validate(Object object) throws ValidationException {
String fieldName = getFieldName();

Object zipObj = this.getFieldValue(fieldName, object);
String country = getCountryCode();
String zipCode = (String) zipObj;

if (zipCode == null || ("".equals(zipCode))) {
  return;
}

boolean valid = false;
try {
  if ((Country.DEFAULT).equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {
    valid = Pattern.matches(US_ZIP_FORMAT, zipCode);
    int testZip = Integer.parseInt(zipCode.substring(0, 5));
    if (testZip == 0) {
      valid = false;
    }
  } else if ((Country.CANADA).equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {
    valid = Pattern.matches(CANADA_ZIP_FORMAT, zipCode);
  } else {
    valid = Pattern.matches(OTHER_ZIP_FORMAT, zipCode);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  logger.error("Cannot validate zip code (" + zipCode + ") for country ("
      + country + ").");
  valid = false;
}

if (!valid) {
  addFieldError(fieldName, object);
}
}
```

How to pass the country code back to the custom validator. This is my `ActionClass-validation.xml`

```xml
<validators>
<field name="address.zip">
    <field-validator type="zipValidator">
        <param name="countryCode">${address.country}</param>
        <message key="errors.zip.invalid" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
</validators>
```

Address object has zip and `countryCode`. I want to validate the zip based on the country. When I debug the above code, `countryCode` has the value `${address.country}`.

How can I get the country property value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend your custom validator from `ValidatorSupport`. Then in the implementation code you can use `parse` method to get the value of parameter if it's an OGNL expression.

```java
String country = (String) parse(this.countryCode, String.class);
```